# OpenSUSE Leap 42.3: How to mount a CIFS file share at boot when the network won't start?

Tags: opensuse, networkmanager

I am using OpenSUSE Leap 42.3

I have a CIFS mount entry in my /etc/fstab which mounts a Samba share from a fileshare server.

However my network connection is through Wifi which only activates when I log in to the desktop via Network Manager.

By this time the mount attempt at boot time has already failed because no Wifi connection was active.

How do I make sure there is an active Wifi connection before the cifs file share is mounted?

Comment: ages back (opensuse 10 or 11) I had a shell script called on login (.bash_profile probably) that (a) checked not already mounted, and (b) pinged my file.server (nas using samba).   If (a)not_mounted && (b)server.up (ie. connected to correct network & server responded) it then mounted the share.  it was a 'hack' but worked.

Comment: If you add the options `nofail,user` to the fstab entry, the mount should not fail at boot if there is no network connection to the server. After you logged in, you may manually mount the drive (or have the mount command in some `ifup`script).

Answer (score 0):

Network manager should have it's own dispatcher hooks running on a state change. They are located in the /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d

You can create a script of the kind:

```
===== 50-smb-mount =====
#! /bin/sh

case "$2" in
   up)
              mount -a -t cifs
              ;;
   down)
              umount -a -t cifs
              ;;
esac

========================
```

Do not forget to chmod +x it.

In addition you may add 'user,nofail' options in your fstab cifs entries.